# View/extract embedded archives with RAR

Tags: macos, terminal, archive, rar

So I have something like this:

[image]

I got this with `rar l file2.rar`

This basically is one archive inside of another.

Is there any way to list/extract the contents of `file.rar` that is inside `file2.rar` with RAR for terminal without extraction?

Note: I am using RAR 5.50 on macOS High Sierra.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that it is possible to do with Midnight Commander.